# How to write a list to a JSON file without losing the comma

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to develop code in Python that formats a list in a JSON file without removing the commas or brackets. The list is supposed to have each set of data on a new line. I'm able to handle the brackets on my own, but I'm having issues with the commas.

I've already tried include a indent statement in .dump, but it's not the correct format.

```
    #Attempt 1

    for data in data:
        outfile.write('\t')
        json.dump(data, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')

    #Attempt 2
    for obj in data:
        outfile.write('\t' + json.dumps(obj) + '\n')
```

Expected output

```
[
    [1, 12],
    [2, 7],
    [3, 6]
]
```

Actual output

```
[
    [1, 12]
    [2, 7]
    [3, 6]
]
```

Comment: Bluntly, it'd do a lot of good to get the specification updated so you aren't needing to write regular JSON (needing a `[` in front, a `]` in back, and a comma after all but the last line) but instead JSONL, where you simply have a line per item; no end-of-line commas, no `[` header or `]` footer. That not only makes your code shorter -- it also makes the OS's syscall layer map better to your needs, such that atomic append operations are possible even with multiple concurrent writers (should they use `O_APPEND`).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This isn’t valid json.

Comment: @oefe, the *expected* output is valid JSON; it's the *actual* output that isn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry, you’re right, I missread the question

Answer (score 4):

Why are you iterating at all? You should just dump the whole list in one go:

```
outfile.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: The OP is trying to format the json in a specific way: "The list is supposed to have each set of data on a new line. "

Comment: Or `json.dump(data, outfile)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your `Attempt 2` to add the comma to each outputted item except the last:

```
for ndx, obj in enumerate(data, 1):
    outfile.write(
        '\t'
        + json.dumps(obj)
        + (',' if ndx != len(data) else '')
        + '\n'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like:

```
# Python 3+
import json

objects = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
# the magic happens next line:
dump = "[\n" + ",\n".join([ "\t" + json.dumps(obj) for obj in objects ]) + "\n]"
print(dump)

with open("out", "w") as outfile:
  outfile.write(dump)
```

`json.dumps(obj)` outputs JSON representation of the object as string. A tab character is appended to each object representation and they are joined using `,\n`.

Output:

```
[
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
]
```