# When writing a Data-set to Json file, only the last value from the dataset get is printed

Tags: python

As per a Test data requirement,  I want to assign random values to 3 fields and create a json file with defined number of entries of it .

I had an issue of not printing , at each json key value set so I tired this .
[How to write a list to a JSON file without losing the comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622248/how-to-write-a-list-to-a-json-file-without-losing-the-comma)

But for below code only the last key value pair  get printed.

```
import random
import string
import json


#setup a function to generate random text with length=32 as default variable and value.
def myrandomStringFunc(length=32):
    myCharacterSet=string.ascii_letters
    return ''.join(random.choice(myCharacterSet)for i in range(length))
    #this will print the range of 32 character

def dataAssignment():
  for x in range(5):
      myVal=myrandomStringFunc()
      myVa2=myrandomStringFunc(40)
      myVa3=myrandomStringFunc(50)
      objects = {"key1": myVal, "key2": myVa2, "key3": myVa3}
      print (objects)
      
  return objects

#Call the function.
BulkData=dataAssignment()
print(BulkData)
print("The end of bulk data")
# To add a , comma at everyline if not the last line.
dump = "[\n" + ",\n".join([ "\t" + json.dumps(BulkData) for obj in BulkData ]) + "\n]"
print("The dumb before writing")
print(dump)

with open("DEMO.json", "a") as outfile:
  outfile.write(dump)
```

Output Json file-

```
[
    {"key1": "hMisVssxsVJPsgLKioeAucJiLhtMEKco", "key2": "rLnvblxFDDfrTSKUhUKYCtCNHNvZrMKGEpmOfZoy", "key3": "YQcAPrwQYkCPQizapooUQZYNDkNjqORSpQbJthxBtCNhLbdZPM"},
    {"key1": "hMisVssxsVJPsgLKioeAucJiLhtMEKco", "key2": "rLnvblxFDDfrTSKUhUKYCtCNHNvZrMKGEpmOfZoy", "key3": "YQcAPrwQYkCPQizapooUQZYNDkNjqORSpQbJthxBtCNhLbdZPM"},
    {"key1": "hMisVssxsVJPsgLKioeAucJiLhtMEKco", "key2": "rLnvblxFDDfrTSKUhUKYCtCNHNvZrMKGEpmOfZoy", "key3": "YQcAPrwQYkCPQizapooUQZYNDkNjqORSpQbJthxBtCNhLbdZPM"}
]
```

Console output image-
[image]

Comment: Your `dataAssignment` function prints `objects` for every loop but only returns the `objects` variable from the last loop. You need to either make the function return a single `objects` and then call the function 5 fimes, or build a container inside the function that has all of your `objects` variables and return that container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
objects = {"key1": myVal, "key2": myVa2, "key3": myVa3}
```

this line overwrite `objects` each loop. by the way, you can dump json to file by `json.dump`:

```py
import random
import string
import json


# setup a function to generate random text with length=32 as default variable and value.
def myrandomStringFunc(length=32):
    myCharacterSet = string.ascii_letters
    return ''.join(random.choice(myCharacterSet)for i in range(length))
    # this will print the range of 32 character


def dataAssignment():
    objects = []
    for x in range(5):
        myVal = myrandomStringFunc()
        myVa2 = myrandomStringFunc(40)
        myVa3 = myrandomStringFunc(50)
        objects.append({"key1": myVal, "key2": myVa2, "key3": myVa3})
        # print(objects)

    return objects


# Call the function.
BulkData = dataAssignment()
print(BulkData)

with open("DEMO.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(BulkData, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot shdxiang and  Chillie, you made my day.